# Different output for Dev C++ and VSCode

Tags: c, ide

I have the same code written between the IDEs, but for some reason, they have different results.

My program checks whether the given number input is a palindrome or not, say if the user input is 101 then in Dev C++ it prints out "palindrome" but in the case of using VSCode it prints out "not a palindrome". I have checked my code a lot of times and I don't see any syntax errors. I've searched for similar cases of this problem but I can't really apply or fully understand the solutions given in the post as they're using a different programming language and I'm still new to C.

```
int displayRev(int nNum)
{
    int remainder, revNumber = 0;
    
    while(nNum > 0)
    {
            remainder = nNum % 10;
        nNum = nNum / 10;
        revNumber = (revNumber * 10)+ remainder;
    }
    return revNumber;
}

int display7(int nNum)
{
    int nNum1 = displayRev(nNum);
    
    if (nNum == nNum1)
    {
        printf("palindrome");
    }
    else printf("not a palindrome");
}

int main()
{
    int nNum;
    
    printf ("Enter Number: "); 
    scanf ("%d", &nNum);
   
    display7(nNum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I did check for the compiler and both IDEs are using the same compiler, the version of my GCC MinGW compiler is 6.3.0. I have tried executing the code in cmd and the output is still different from that of the Dev C++. Did I make a mistake in writing the code? or there is a different problem?

Comment: In the `displayRev` function, what is the *initial* value of `revNumber`? Remember that uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized, with an *indeterminate* value (think of its value as being garbage).

Comment: The problem with garbage (indeterminate) values should have been clear if you learned how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Being able to debug ones program is a necessary skill for any programmer. For example using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) you can step through your code, step into function calls, and monitor variables and their values to see how they change.

Comment: Hello, @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you for your feedback. I've changed the problem with the uninitialized variable, but I'm still encountering the same problem of having different outputs for the two IDEs.

Comment: What if you print out the input given, does it match with what you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing enough detail about how you invoke the programs; if you run them straight from some IDE there's a chance the input is failing.

In any case, I think you should:

1. Check that the `scanf()` call actually succeeds before relying on the result,
2. Print the actual number that was processed too, to make it easier to verify.

So change the `main()` to:

```
int main(void)
{
    int nNum;

    printf("Enter Number: "); 
    if (scanf ("%d", &nNum) == 1)
    {
       display7(nNum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then inside the checking function make it something like:

```
int display7(int nNum)
{
    const int nRevNum = displayRev(nNum);
    
    printf("%d: ", nNum);
    if (nNum == nRevNum)
        printf("palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("not a palindrome\n");
}
```